# How to define a prototype scoped bean in Groovy spring DSL

Tags: spring, grails-3.0

In grails one defines spring beans in `resources.groovy` using the spring groovy DSL

```
beans = {
    myBean(MyBeanImpl) {
        someProperty = 42
        otherProperty = "blue"
        bookService = ref("bookService")
    }
}
```

How do you define prototype scoped bean using this DSL? I couldnt find anything on this in the [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/spring.html)

Comment: "I couldnt find anything on this in the documentation" - Under section 18.3 there is an example that configures the sessionFactory bean to be request scoped.  The example doesn't specifically show how to configure a prototype scoped bean, but the syntax is the same for all scopes.  Just replace "request" with "prototype".

Comment: @JeffScottBrown sorry, i missed that. I skimmed and searched for prototype in that document

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
beans = {
    myBean(MyBeanImpl) { bean ->
        bean.scope = 'prototype'
        someProperty = 42
        otherProperty = "blue"
        bookService = ref("bookService")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I am using grails 2.4.4. Can you provide some help?

Comment: @Richa Without knowing what you are doing and what in particular isn't working, it would be very difficult to provide help.  What is shown above does work and always has. There must be some other factor in your application that is complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeff Scott Brown.

How do you know it doesn't work? We're using Grails 2.3.9.

I have this in my resources.groovy:

```
httpBuilderPool(HTTPBuilder) { bean ->
    bean.scope = 'prototype'    // A new service is created every time it is injected into another class
    client = ref('httpClientPool')
}

...
```

and this in a Spock Integration Test:

```
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

class JukinHttpBuilderSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass())

    def httpBuilderPool
    def grailsApplication

    void "test jukinHttpBuilder instantiates"() {
        expect:
        httpBuilderPool
        httpBuilderPool.client instanceof CloseableHttpClient
    }

    void "test httpBuilderPool is prototype instaance"() {
        when: 'we call getBean on the application context'
        def someInstanceIds = (1..5).collect { grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('httpBuilderPool').toString() }.toSet()
        log.info someInstanceIds.toString()

        then: 'we should get a new instance every access'
        someInstanceIds.size() == 5
    }

    void "test injected httpBuilderPool is prototype instance"() {
        when: 'we access the injeted httpBuilderPool'
        def someInstanceIds = (1..5).collect { httpBuilderPool.toString() }.toSet()
        log.info someInstanceIds.toString()

        then: 'it uses the same instance every time'
        someInstanceIds.size() == 1
    }
}
```

which shows me it works in 2.3.9.